# Почему не отображается django select2?

Tags: python, django, select2

поставил [django-select2](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-select2) по [этой](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) и [этой](https://michelenasti.com/2021/02/12/how-to-integrate-a-django_select2-component-in-django-admin.html) инструкции, но select не показывает, в чем дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_select2',
]
```

**main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    ]
```

**app models.py**

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone
```

**app forms.py**

```
class PhoneSelect2Widget(s2forms.ModelSelect2Widget):
    search_fields = ('phone__icontains',)
    queryset = Clients.objects.all()

class RelatedAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=PhoneSelect2Widget,
        queryset=Clients.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(RelatedAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['phone'].label = 'Телефон'

    class Meta:
        model = Clients
        fields = ['phone']
```

**html**

```
<head>
...  
<script src="/static/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script
...   
</head>
<body>
...
<select name="clients-phone" lang="ru" data-minimum-input-length="2"
         data-theme="default" data-allow-clear="false" data-ajax--url="/select2/fields/auto.json"
     data-ajax--cache="true" data-ajax--
        type="GET" class="select2 django-select2 django-select2-heavy" required="" id="id_clients-phone" data-
        field_id="IjhlNDRlZjNhLTU3NGYtNDBhZC1iYjdlLTk0YmNjZDA4Zjk1YSI:1qSxRI:z4boTWi5hy1iJFmT968PxuRP6_sgoAKktThsPYp3mmI">
</select>
...
</body>
```

Comment: глубоко не углублялся в проблему твою. Но по первой ссылке увидел кэш. Так же не вижу Вьюхи у тебя. Ты уверен, что ты весь код скопировал?

Comment: кеш не ставил, думал без него должен работать? а там кеш можно поставить на mysql или надо redis?

Comment: Что-то я не понял, django-select2 предназначен для выбора связанной модели, а вы почему-то пытаетесь его навесить на текстовое поле — сильно сомневаюсь, что разработчики django-select2 предполагали такой сценарий использования

Comment: Выведите список не в селект а что то другое, возможно вы не передали значение на страницу.